# Difficulty of finding a claw for AES-CMAC

Tags: collision-resistance

Consider the problem of finding two keys K1 and K2, such that for two distinct plaintexts P1 and P2, AES-CMAC(K1, P1) = AES-CMAC(K2, P2).

Is this problem any easier than brute-forcing? If so, how much easier?

Edit: plaintexts P1 and P2 are inputs to the problem and therefore they are fixed. We need to find the keys given the pair of inputs.

Comment: What would you count as "brute-forcing"? Would that cover the generic collision-search attack with cost $\mathcal O\left(2^{|T|/2}\right)$, where $|T|$ is the width of the tag $T$ (noted _Tlen_ in [NIST SP 800-38B](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/specialpublications/nist.sp.800-38b.pdf#page=9)), which applies generically to any MAC?

Comment: It's usually not desirable to edit your question in a way that invalidates an existing answer.  If you discover that you asked the wrong question, it's often better to take that as a sign to be more careful to state the question precisely from the start in the future, and ask a new question with the correct formulation.

Answer (score 3):

> If so, how much easier?

Much easier.  If you know the key, it is trivial to craft a message that CMACs to any specific value.

Here's one approach: the output of CMAC (assuming that the last block $M$ is full) is:

$$AES_k( PrevState \oplus k_1 \oplus M )$$

where $PrevState$ is the 16 byte state resulting from the previous message blocks, and $k_1$ is the tweak applied to the last message block (for full last message blocks).

So, the attacker arbitrarily selects the previous message blocks; given that he knows the key, he can compute $PrevState$ and $k_1$.  So, to get a target output $T$, he just computes

$$M = AES_k^{-1}( T ) \oplus PrevState \oplus k_1$$

and that's the last message block.

To generate a collision, he can pick an arbitrary output block $T$ and generate two messages using the above mechanism.

---

If the two messages $P_1, P_2$ are fixed, then it is more difficult (although still computationally feasible, by the current definition of 'feasible').

You're stuck with doing a straight-forward birthday attack (as AES doesn't have any internal weaknesses you can exploit).  In essense, you do:

- Select $2^{64}$ values of $k_1$, and compute the values $CMAC_{k_1}( P_1 )$
- Select $2^{64}$ values of $k_2$, and compute the values $CMAC_{k_2}( P_2 )$

Search the two lists for a collision.

If you don't want to take up $O(2^{64})$ memory, there are ways to optimize this that drastically reduce the memory and increase the processing by a small constant factor.

Still, we're talking about circa $2^{65}$ CMAC computations; feasible if you have a large budget, but not so much for an average hacker with a laptop...

Comment: See my edit. I cannot craft any message -- the messages are fixed and given as inputs.